# Why vectors inside two struct have the same address?

Tags: c++

For avoid duplicate code, i want to build this generic structure. I want the numbers24 vector inside the scaledown24 struct to be different from the numbers32 vector inside the scaledown32 struct. So when I make a change, they won't be able to influence each other. But when I run the program, the printAddress function shows that the address of the two vectors is the same. How can i fix this. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct ScaleDown24{
    static std::vector<int> getVector() {
        std::vector<int> numbers24(3);
        return numbers24;
    };
    static inline void printAddress(std::vector<int>sumNumbers ) {
        std::vector<int> *p = &sumNumbers;
        std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
};

struct ScaleDown32{
    static std::vector<int> getVector() {
        std::vector<int> numbers32(4);
        return numbers32;
    };
    static inline void printAddress(std::vector<int>sumNumbers ) {
        std::vector<int> *p = &sumNumbers;
        std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename ScaleFunction>
void scaleDown(){
    std::vector<int>sumNumbers = ScaleFunction::getVector();
    ScaleFunction::printAddress(sumNumbers);

}

int main()
{
    scaleDown<ScaleDown24>();
    scaleDown<ScaleDown32>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.  Mainly stemming from the fact that both `getVector()` methods return their vectors **by value**, and both `printAddress()` methods take their arguments **by value** as well.  So you are dealing with *copies* of vectors all over the place.  You are seeing memory getting reused in different contexts.

You need to introduce some *references* into your code to avoid those copies, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct ScaleDown24{
    static std::vector<int>& getVector() { // <-- return a reference
        static std::vector<int> numbers24(3); // <-- make static to avoid returning a reference to a local variable
        return numbers24;
    };
    static inline void printAddress(const std::vector<int> &sumNumbers ) { // <-- take a const reference
        const std::vector<int> *p = &sumNumbers;
        std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
};

struct ScaleDown32{
    static std::vector<int>& getVector() { // <-- return a reference
        static std::vector<int> numbers32(4); // <-- make static to avoid returning a reference to a local variable
        return numbers32;
    };
    static inline void printAddress(const std::vector<int> &sumNumbers) { // <-- take a const reference
        const std::vector<int> *p = &sumNumbers;
        std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename ScaleFunction>
void scaleDown(){
    std::vector<int> &sumNumbers = ScaleFunction::getVector(); // <-- save a reference, not a local copy
    ScaleFunction::printAddress(sumNumbers); // <-- prints the original vector that is inside getVector()!
}

int main()
{
    scaleDown<ScaleDown24>();
    scaleDown<ScaleDown32>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/pH3zW8)

Answer (score 3):

Your `printAddress()` function takes its argument **by value**.  That means you are *making a copy* of any `vector` that you pass to it, and it is that copy that you are printing the address of.

What you need to do is pass the vector argument **by reference** instead, so that you can get the address of the original, not a copy.  That would look like this:

```
static inline void printAddress(std::vector<int>& sumNumbers )
//                         this means reference ^
```

You are also going to have an issue with `scaleDown()`:

```
template<typename ScaleFunction>
void scaleDown(){
    std::vector<int>sumNumbers = ScaleFunction::getVector();
    ScaleFunction::printAddress(sumNumbers);

}
```

because `sumNumbers` is a non-static local variable so it can have the same address each time you call that function.  If you just want each `ScaleFunction` to have its own vector, you can make it `static to do that like this:

```
template<typename ScaleFunction>
void scaleDown(){
    static std::vector<int>sumNumbers = ScaleFunction::getVector();
    ScaleFunction::printAddress(sumNumbers);

}
```

---

Also note that since `printAddress()` doesn't modify the vector, and you don't want it to, you can make the vector `const` to help enforce that.  That would give you this:

```
static inline void printAddress(const std::vector<int>& sumNumbers ) {
    // no need for the pointer here
    std::cout << &sumNumbers << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is only half the problem.  In `scaleDown`, `sumNumbers` is a local.  It might ([and indeed does](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SXIJg6KAMhJ0BKGY)) wind up at the same location in both invocations.

Comment: `printAddress()` should take its argument by `const` reference, since it does not modify the argument: `static inline void printAddress(const std::vector<int>& sumNumbers )`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point, I've added that into the answer.  Also, thanks for the edit

Comment: @PaulSanders Good spot.  I've added a potential fix for that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Remi's answer working true.